# How to compress 2 (apple) disk images of different backups of the same drive?

Tags: macos, mac, backup, compression, dmg-image

So I have backed up my Macintosh HD at different instances to DMG files.  I would like to compress them but when I try to make an archive it simply compresses each image, without recognizing the similarities in the content of the images (only a few GB of differences in ~70GB of data).  The resulting size of the archive is about the same as the sum of sizes of a compressed DMG for each backup (I checked). I don't have them compressed or encrypted as I hoped this would help.  I wonder if there is a way to get a compression program to recognize the duplicate content in the uncompressed disk images.  Would creating a compressed DMG with 2 partitions (one for each backup of my original disk) work?  If so how would I go about that?  There must be a way to do this...

Comment: If making a new DMG is not out of the question, http://superuser.com/questions/342259 might be of some help to you.  Another way would be to compare the contents of your two DMGs, and delete the duplicate files from one before compacting/compressing it.  (The "compact" only works if the DMG is a sparse image file).  Simplest(?) of all would be to connect an external HDD and let TimeMachine manage all the backups for you.

Comment: Are you sure they're not compressed? Exactly which of the .dmg disk image formats are they, then? Use `hdiuitl imageinfo filename.dmg` to double-check. Are they UDRW? UDRO?